# Do I need to shut down before powering off a VM?

Tags: windows, vmware-workstation

Sometimes I'm starting a VM to do a quick test. I start up the VM, do the test and then power off. However, doing this I get the warning

> Check that you have shut down your guest operating system before powering off.
>
> Are you sure you want to power off the virtual machine ""?
>
> [ ] Do not show this message again.

Reading some [VMWare documentation about Power off](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_poweroff_vs_shutdown.html), I understand that there may be data/disk corruptions if the power off occurs during a write operation.

Given the fact that I will always revert to a snapshot and not power on from the state I powered off, is there any risk in powering off a running VM?

In my opinion, the data of that session should be written into a new disk file which will be deleted when reverting to another snapshot. Is this correct?

> Versions:
>   VMWare: 10.0.1
>   Guest OS: all Windows only (but shouldn't actually matter)
>   Host OS: Windows 7 (should also not matter)

Comment: Finish all your work in guest os and you can power off!
I always do that in windows xp in virtualbox,and it still run well!
(Try it on your own risk)
(as also described data corruption may be occurs when a write operation,so save all your work,if guest os is really important to you,i'll recommend you to proper shutdown!)

Comment: and in virtualbox,you can save many snapshots as you want! (i know only about virtualbox,cause i use it! :) )
This should be in vmware too,you can check it by taking two or many snapshots and then start it from one by one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always revert to a stable (consistent) snapshot there is no problem in powering off the VM.

Immediate poweroffs can result in filesystem inconsistencies because there might still be unflushed caches in memory or write operations in progress. Since you are reverting to a snapshot, which always has a consistent state, there shouldn't be any problem.

Keep in mind if you make changes to your disk, and want to create a new snapshot from that, you should shutdown gracefully (to prevent filesystem corruption).

Answer (score 0):

Turning off a VM is roughly the same as turning off your physical machine. I've done it heaps of times...but that doesn't mean that the OS that's running inside won't complain the next time you start up.

However, as others have already mentioned, snaphots can save the day.

The *proper* answer would be to suggest to *always* shutdown (or save state)

Comment: On a physical machine you have only 1 hard disk and you don't revert, so it cannot be really compared to each other.

Comment: @Thomas W. My thinking was more toward the OS itself...Windows itself doesn't like when the machine - virtual or otherwise - is just turned off. As you noted & Op mentions that he reverts all the time: so yes, no harm done (as long as you revert)